# How to make a custom toast fill width?

Tags: android

How can you make a custom toast notification fill the width of the screen?

I have tried multiple things and can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This should work:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This works fine, but the toast is displayed as center_horizental. Can we have Fill_Horizontal and BOTTOM together?

Comment: @KaiWang you could just add | operator like this: toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

Comment: @Cody Unfortunately if the message is long, it doesn't obey the Gravity.BOTTOM for some reason, and leaves a gap equal to a line of text below the toast. It's very frustrating!

Comment: @JakeSteam Did you find the solution for this issue of blank space below toast?

Comment: @ctor That was 3 years ago, I honestly can't remember. Sorry friend.

Comment: old but still work. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can create toast with custom layout and fill_horizontal. Below code is written in Adapter class and it is working fine.

```
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)mContext
                                     .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,null);

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

            Toast toast = new Toast(mContext);

            //use both property in single function
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
```

Comment: In Kotlin you can do this `setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find here http://android-apps-blog.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-display-custom-toast-in-android.html a good tutorian on How to create a Custom Toast Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [example](http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/161) for Custom Toast with Border.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should make a Dialog or an activity (with the dialog theme or something you've made that looks like the dialog theme), and show that.

Use a timer in the oncreate that calls `finish()` after your time is up.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
    wM = (WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
        // Set the layout to be like a toast window!
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.WHEREVER YOU WANT IT TO BE
            mParams.height = 200;
    mParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    mParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    mParams.format = PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;

            wm.addView(v);

            <Timer or whatever>

            wm.removeView(v);
```